# Multiplayer game in iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, google-play-services, google-play-games

After updating the plugin, the Google+ SDK for iOS and Google Play Games SDK for iOS to their latest versions, I'm running with a problem.

If I try to invite a friend for a match, after touching the play button, the game crashes and the output is the next:

```
2014-11-13 18:44:40.683 multiplayer[1528:1297541] INFO:Connect with retry.getRetryAuthToken():1
2014-11-13 18:44:40.684 multiplayer[1528:1297541] INFO:Token expired. Refreshing.
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::__1::system_error:condition_variable::timed wait:mutex not locked:Operation not permitted
```

What can I do in this case? That issue is stopping me from sending a release candidate to a publisher.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: post the code that crashes

Comment: - (void)startQuickMatchGameWithTotalPlayers:(int)totalPlayers {
    
    if (![GPGManager sharedInstance].isSignedIn) {
        [self requestSignIn];
        return;
    }
    
    GPGMultiplayerConfig *config = [[GPGMultiplayerConfig alloc] init];
    // Could also include variants or exclusive bitmasks here
    config.minAutoMatchingPlayers =1;
    config.maxAutoMatchingPlayers =1;
    
    // Show waiting room UI
    [[GPGLauncherController sharedInstance] presentRealTimeWaitingRoomWithConfig:config];
}

Comment: edit the question with your code

Comment: Same problem, do you find a solution?

Comment: Just to add more info to this: "In addition i can say that problem doesn't occur on the simulators and probably on new 64bit devices. We’ve tested quick game in iPhone 6 and there were not errors, but the same build doesn't work on iPad mini and iPhone 5."